# Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource' to type 'System.Data.DataTable'

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm having a weird issue with my code. I'm currently coding a filter for my datagrid.

Whenever the user clears the text field - the following error message is brought up:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource' to
>   type 'System.Data.DataTable'.

This is my code so far:

```
    private void driverNo_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // if driverNo text is empty then return all rows

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(driverNo.Text))
        {
            ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Empty;
            return;
        }

        // if driverNo is a numerical value then view result

        int temp;
        if (int.TryParse(driverNo.Text, out temp))
            ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = "DriverNo = " + driverNo.Text;
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid driver number.");
            driverNo.Text = "";
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `DataSource` is a type of `BindingSource`, not `DataTable`. Basically your expectation is incorrect. It is possible the `DataTable` is actually backing the `BindingSource`.

You very likely have a `BindingSource` component on your WinForms design surface. You can get to the table via something like the following:

```
var bindingSource = this.myBindingSource;
var dt = (DataTable)bindingSource.DataSource;
```

You can indirectly get to it via:

```
var bindingSource = (BindingSource)dataGridView1.DataSource;
var dt = (DataTable)bindingSource.DataSource;
```

---

For your code it might look like this:

```
private void driverNo_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // if driverNo text is empty then return all rows

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(driverNo.Text))
    {
        var bindingSource = (BindingSource)dataGridView1.DataSource.
        var table = (DataTable)bindingSource.DataSource;
        table.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Empty;
        return;
    }

    // if driverNo is a numerical value then view result

    int temp;
    if (int.TryParse(driverNo.Text, out temp))
    {
        var bindingSource = (BindingSource)dataGridView1.DataSource.
        var table = (DataTable)bindingSource.DataSource;
        table.DefaultView.RowFilter = "DriverNo = " + driverNo.Text;
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid driver number.");
        driverNo.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: @methuselah It would look like the above, instead of `((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource)`

Comment: With the above - I get the error message: `Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource' does not contain a definition for 'DefaultView' and no extension method 'DefaultView' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: @methuselah Give me a minute and I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
DataTable dt = ((DataView)gridView1.DataSource).Table;

DataView dv = (DataView)gridView1.DataSource;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
        `xxxBindingSource.AddNew();`
        `dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value = "Value Here";`
        `dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value = "Value here";`
        `xxxBindingSource.EndEdit();`
```

Comment: Please explain your code. And the formatting of your code block is off.

Comment: The proposed code need explanation how it is related to the question.